# How should I feed and keep an ant queen?

Tags: metabolism, experiment, ant

I have captured wandering ant queen. I guess she was just fertilised and was looking for a place to start a hive.
I'd like to create my own ant hive in artificial environment.

I unfortunately only have a small clean chemical bottle (1.5 CM in radius) to keep her in. I was wondering how much space would she need to feel safe.

I'm also not sure what should I feed her. Every morning, I have dropped few sugar crystals in the bottle. She shows much more individuality than an ant, because she has immediately started to collect them. It seems that she ate almost everything. I have also dropped few tiny drops of water in the bottle. Although it's hot and she ate the dry sugar she doesn't seem to drink it at all.

So what does she need? (well, except of natural forest which I don't have in my room)

Comment: Why this was downvoted? is it not acceptable question or how it could be improved?

Comment: @ruffp Feel free to upvote, like I did (and always do). I agree, the question is entirely on-topic.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to identify your ant, for Czech Ants: http://www.antweb.org/taxonomicPage.do?rank=species&project=czechants&images=true

### How should I feed and keep an ant queen?

**Home for Pet Ant, Ant Farm:**

There are lots of things you can use, for example, a clean transparent glass or plastic jar, or a fish tank of a size which you will decide is best for the ants you're keeping in it. As long as the container provides enough space, and the addition of any air holes small enough to prevent the ants escaping (much easier said than done); and also so you can observe your ants going about their daily activities, then it should be fine! Worker ants like to forage, so your set up needs to allow for the ants to do a spot of hunting for their food.

It is possible to make your own type of "Ant Farm" by using lengths of wood or plastic which have 2 grooves cut into them, like the frame used in double glazing. As long as you can place the frame onto a sturdy base to prevent it from falling over; or you can use plaster and other materials such as aerated concrete blocks, better known as Ytong nests. Two panes of clear glass or plastic can be placed into the grooves and sealed. Use the silicone sealant that is used around baths or sold where you buy glass fish tanks, but do remember to let it set and dry out well, as this will allow any chemicals to disperse harmlessly into the air before you add any ants. Also make sure that you can safely access your ant home, so you can put food in etc. You can also check out this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQEar1JLR5E) or [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Build-an-Ant-Farm).
[image]
Always try to cover your ants when not observing them to exclude light, as for most of their lives ants live in underground nests or places well away from daylight. This does not mean that they won't tolerate light; but they prefer to be in total darkness if possible, and queens rarely come out from their nests in the wild.

**Feed the ANT:**

If you are using a  gel-filled ant farms, it  contains all the water and nutrients your ants need for survival. Make sure to keep your kit sealed so the gel does not dry out.
[image]
[image]

In sand-filled ant farms, you need to add a few drops of water and small bits of food every few days. Ants also love a special treat of water with sugar dissolved in it, but this can’t take the place of fresh water for drinking. You can provide them with a bit of honey at times, and they will probably drink some of that. A small section of meal-worm can help provide her with a protein boost. Again, feeding them until the first workers arrive is not necessary as they do not forage during this period naturally.
[image]

Moreover, Interesting Links:

http://askabiologist.asu.edu/collecting-queen-ants

http://ant-farm-stores-review.toptenreviews.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-ant-farms.html

www.tarheelants.com/

Also, try "Ants can be pets" group on Facebook.

Comment: Your PDF link is aimed to distinct ant workers, which might look differently than queens. It also only applies on species that live in united states and are considered harmful. You're also generally takling about making the colony - not very much about the queen herself. In an answer on another question, which you have deleted, you claimed she doesn't eat at all...

Comment: Sorry, you never gave your geographical region, I have removed that part. As for the last deleted question, I was trying to explain the general scenario. Queen ants doesn't eat after laying eggs as they fend of there flight muscle. It doesn't mean she doesn't eat if given provided to her, she even eat her eggs if she is hungry. There various links says the same thing: www.animals.howstuffworks.com/insects/ant-info3.htm

PS: I don't know why you have me so much. All the answer I gave are mostly liked, if not, I just remove them. I love Biology SO and I am not leaving here.