# Can I identify this black ant queen?

Tags: species-identification, ant

I have an ant queen in a jar. This is what she looks like:

[image: black ant queen captured in jar]

Because I'm planning to start an artificial ant nest, I'd like to learn something about that specific species of ant. This particular queen is very common in the Czech Republic, central Europe. It's also very common in cities.

1. Could you tell what kind of queen is that?
2. Is there any image reference that would help me find out? Ideally with some location search possibility.

Comment: I am not an expert of ants, but it looks very much like the common black garden ant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_garden_ant

Comment: For a moment, I hoped she will be some special badass ant queen. But I love her anyway.

Comment: This is not a common black garden ant "Lasius niger" because these ants do not have alternate mat and shiny bands on the gaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be a Lasius queen, it is a Formica queen. Although one of the main characteristic is the shape of the first segment of the funicula which cannot be seen on this picture, the general aspect of this queen (elongated, with red legs, does not have a bulky aspect) indicates this queen is from the genus Formica. It is similar in shape and coloration to many queens in the subgenus Serviformica, for example Formica cunicularia, Formica cinerea.

Answer (score 1):

As @skymnige said it is definitely **Black garden ant (*Lasius niger*)**

[image]

Comment: This is wrong, the pronotum is not elevated enough, the tergites that are half mat and half shiny don't match with Lasius, same for the general aspect of the ant (more elongated than Lasius), the legs are dark red which is common in the genus Formica whereas they are more often black or yellow in Lasius.

Comment: @Nakx: I believe you are right. https://www.antsrus.com/store/p80/Formica_%28Serviformica%29_cunicularia_Queen_with_1-5_workers_%28Starter_pack%29.html

Comment: Thank you @Devashish_Das, I am an ant taxonomist and most ant identifications on stack biology are wrong.